# How do I print out this list of lists?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, indexing

```
count: int = 0
while count < len(stocksOwned):
    print(stocksOwned[count][count][0],'\nsakuma cena-',stocksOwned[count][count][1])
    count += 1

stocksOwned = [[['Microsoft', 150, 0.01, 0, 0]], [['Tesla', 710, 0.0424, 0, 0]]]
```

> Traceback: print(stocksOwned[0][count][0],'\nsakuma
>   cena-',stocksOwned[0][count][1]) IndexError: list index out of range

I can't seem to figure why the index is out of range. I know indexing starts with 0. What am I not seeing or understanding  here?

Comment: You have 6 different places where this error can occur on that line. You need to narrow down where the error actually happens. Break the problem into smaller pieces by printing `stocksOwned[count]` and `stocksOwned[count][count]` to see what happens.

Comment: Also, the error message you show here doesn't match the code. Be sure you post the correct version of your code that causes the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `stocksOwned[count][count]` and this results to the error based on `stocksOwned = [[['Microsoft', 150, 0.01, 0, 0]], [['Tesla', 710, 0.0424, 0, 0]]]`.
Use the following code:

```
while count < len(stocksOwned):
    print(stocksOwned[count][0][0],'\nsakuma cena-',stocksOwned[count][0][1])
    count += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

This is actually a list of lists of lists... Here's how you print:

```
for stock in stocksOwned:
     print(stock[0][0],'\nsakuma cena-',stock[0][1])
```

You may mean to have:
`stocksOwned = [['Microsoft', 150, 0.01, 0, 0], ['Tesla', 710, 0.0424, 0, 0]]` (a list of lists)

Comment: I just want to emphasize to the OP that this is a cleaner way of writing a loop in Python than using a counter for the index.

Answer (score 0):

Your second dimension of list has only 1 index.

```
stocksOwned[count][0][0]
```

will give you the correct value. Having `stocksOwned[count][count][0]` will make it index the next list which is not there.

```
stocksOwned[0]
[['Microsoft', 150, 0.01, 0, 0]]
stocksOwned[0][0]
['Microsoft', 150, 0.01, 0, 0]
stocksOwned[0][0][0]
'Microsoft'
```

This is how it looks. so indexing 1 in the middle one will throw error.